# std::string::replace "no matching function for call" error

Tags: c++

I really don't know how to make this program work correctly. The only problem at the moment is the `replace`. I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong with it? We're only allowed to use `if`-`else`, and `while` statements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

   /*i becomes !
     a becomes @
     m becomes M
     B becomes 8
     o becomes .
     append q*s */

   string passWord;

   cin >> passWord;

   char chari = 'i';
   int strLen = passWord.length();
   int curPos = 0;
   int chariIndex = passWord.find(chari);

   while (curPos < strLen) {
      if (passWord.find(chari)) {
         passWord.replace(chariIndex, 1, '!');
         cout << chariIndex << endl;
         curPos += 1;
      } 
   }

   cout << passWord << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which [std::string::replace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) overload are you trying to use? I don't see any that matches your parameters. Btw, `strLen`, `curPos` and `chariIndex` should be `size_t`s, not `int`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling any of the overloads of [`std::string::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace). However, since you are only replacing a single character, instead of `replace`, you could simply do

```
passWord[chariIndex] = '!';
```

If you want to use `replace` then you could call it like this:

```
passWord.replace(chariIndex, 1, "!");
```

Note that the 3rd argument is a `string`, not a `char`.

Also, [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) does not return a `bool`, as you seem to be expecting in your code. You need to compare the result of `find` to `std::string::npos` instead:

```
if (passWord.find(chari) != std::string::npos) {
  // found
```

If you use the result of `find` as a `bool`, it will always evaluate to `true` (unless you find the character at the 0th index).